# Linear non-homogeneous recurrence solution?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following equation:

$$A_{n}=A_{n-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}$$

with the inital conditions $A_1=1$ and $A_2= 1 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Does anyone know how to find the closed form expression?

Comment: I think the best you can get is in series form $$A_n=A_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}.}$$

Comment: @AnuragA That is what I started with. Is there no way to proceed further?

Comment: Tarun, your recursion for $n=2$ gives $A_2=A_1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. This is impossible with $A_1=1$ and $A_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula for a way to approximate that sum

Comment: @Peter Foreman. Just fixed it sorry

Answer (score 0):

*Probably too complex.*

The general solution of 
$$A_{n}=A_{n-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}$$ is
$$A_n=c_1-\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\right) \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appear  the Hurwitz zeta function and the zeta function.

Using $A_1=1$, we then have
$$A_n=1+\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}=1+\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers.

Using, for large values of $p$, the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$H_{p}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2 \sqrt{p}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{p}}+O
\left(\frac{1}{p^{3/2}}\right)$$  we end with
$$A_n=1+\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2n-1}+\frac 1{ 2\sqrt{2n-1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$

Let $n=10^k$ and compute to get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & A_{10 ^k} \approx &  A_{10 ^k} =\\
1 & 4.045878878 & 4.044873362 \\
 2 & 13.71445211 & 13.71442242 \\
 3 & 44.29363302 & 44.29363208 \\
 4 & 140.9936283 & 140.9936283
\end{array}
\right)$$